# Wso2 Upload Service Provider Metadata API

Tags: wso2, x509certificate, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

So I am using Wso2's `IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService` to upload some service provider configuration. However it is not really working out of the box so I though I would update a couple of attributes to see what happens.

What I found though, was that the `IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService` has no update functionality. There are endpoints for

- AddRPServiceProvider
- removeServiceProvider
- uploadServiceProvider

But there is no update.

What is the best way to have specific values for a service provider that is created using the upload functionality ?

Should I add the attributes I want inside the `EntityDescriptor` metadata that gets uploaded ?

Is there some other way of updating a service provider configuration ?

Extra:

- I need to do this through the API so that I can automate the process
- An example attribute I want to update is `certAlias`

Comment: You can use https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityApplicationManagementService?wsdl  update application. For more info you could refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Using+the+Service+Provider+API#UsingtheServiceProviderAPI-updateApplication

Comment: Yeah i am using the services indeed. The issue is that the `updateApplication` endpoint is part of the `IdentityApplicationManagementService` thus there is no option to update the attribute i want. The `certAlias` attribute that i want to update is part of the SSO configuration. Can i update that attribute through the `updateApplication` endpoint ?